# Invalid type argument of -> C structs

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to access items in an array of structs and print the structs fields as follows

```
printList(Album *a, int numOfStructs)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i = 0; i < numOfStructs; i++)
    {
         printf("number%d\n:", i+1);
         printf("%s", a[i]->field2);
         printf("%s", a[i]->field2);
         printf("%d", a[i]->field3);

         for(j = 0; j < a[i]->numOfStrings; j++)
         {
             printf("%s", a[i]->strings[j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
    }
}
```

but I get loads of errors as such

> invalid type argument of '->'

What am I doing wrong with this pointer?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`a` is of type `Album*` which means that `a[i]` is of type `Album` (it is the `i`th element in the array of `Album` object pointed to by `a`).

The left operand of `->` must be a pointer; the `.` operator is used if it is not a pointer.

Answer (score 13):

You need to use the `.` operator. You see, when you apply a `*` to a pointer, you are dereferencing it. The same goes with the `[]`. The difference between `*` and `[]` is that the brackets require an offset from the pointer, which is added to the address in the pointer, before it is dereferenced. Basically, these expressions are identical:

```
*ptr == ptr[0]
*(ptr + 1) == ptr[1]
*(ptr + 2) == ptr[2]
```

To connect to your question: Change `a[i]->field2` and `a[i]->field3` to `a[i].field2` and `a[i].field3`.

Comment: Thanks. different parts of my program need -> and others need . ? I just started with C and as soon as I think I understand pointers, I realize I have no clue. :(  When I try the following   fgets(&(tempAlbum->field1),MAXCHARACTERS, stdin); I get warning: passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type