# c++: invalid type argument of ‘->’

Tags: c++

I get this message when trying to insert an object to a `table` (struct) that holds an array of a struct type `ObjectLink`. The structs:

```
typedef struct ObjectLink {
    void *key;
    struct Object *next;
} ObjectLink;

typedef struct Object {
    void *key;
    ObjectLink *top;
} Object;

typedef struct Table{
    ObjectLink *linkedObjects;
    int size, originalSize;
    HashFcn hfun;
    PrintFcn pfun;
    ComparisonFcn fcomp;
} Table;
```

The code that is failing (on all assignments  & if statement):

```
Boolean InsertObject(TableP table, ObjectP object)
{

    int i = table->hfun(object, table->size);
    if (table->linkedObjects[i]->key == NULL)
    {
        table->linkedObjects[i]->key = object;
    } else
    {
        table->linkedObjects[i]->next->key = object;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I've searched in [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983010/invalid-type-argument-of-c-structs) but that didn't help. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `linkedObjects` is a pointer, `linkedObjects[i]` is the object itself. The `->` operator works only on pointers; when you have a `struct`, you need to use the regular dot operator `.` for field access:

```
table->linkedObjects[i].key = object;
//                     ^--- Here
```

Comment: So why isn't table which is a struct by itself and not a pointer isn't called like: table.linkedObjects[i].key

Comment: @Tom `table` is of type `TableP`, which is not shown in the definitions; however, `P` probably stands for `Pointer`.

Answer (score 3):

The array subscripting operator `[]` is defined as: `E1[E2] == *((E1)+(E2))`. With `->`, you are trying to dereference a pointer which doesn't exist (because you've already dereferenced your pointer with the operator `[]`). So the right solution is:

```
table->linkedObjects[i].next->key = object;
```

Instead of:

```
table->linkedObjects[i]->next->key = object;
```

`linkedObjects[i]` is of type `ObjectLink`, no need to dereference it.