# What is wrong with this header file?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, readdir

I'm fairly new to `C` and am starting to learn header files. Whilst using my header I'm getting an error saying `invalid type argument of '->' (have struct dirent)`. I don't understand what this means, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983010/invalid-type-argument-of-c-structs) that the second argument to `->` must be a pointer, so I tried to add a `*` to it (`ent->*d_name)` however then I get the error unexpected token `*`, how can I fix this?

```
#ifndef UTILIS_H_INCLUDED
#define UTILIS_H_INCLUDED "utilis.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

char *connect(const char *pattern)
{
    struct dirent ent;
    char *d_name;

    DIR *mgt = opendir("\\\\example\\windows7apps");

    while ((ent = readdir(mgt)) != pattern)
    {
        puts(ent->d_name);
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this `readdir` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html). What does `readdir` return? What is the type of `ent`?

Comment: If this is a header, you most definitely don't want the entire function definition in here. Either move it to a .c file or mark it as `inline`.

Comment: @DeiDei What is `inline`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I read here that the second argument to -> must be a pointer,*

That's wrong, the "first" argument, or, actually, the operand of the `->` operator should be of pointer type.

In your case, `ent` is not a pointer type, so you cannot use the pointer member dereference operator `->`. (*you could have used the member dereference operator `.` instead*).

**Actually**, in your code, `ent` should be a pointer, as per the return type of `readdir()`. So you better correct the type of `ent` to be of `struct dirent *`, then you can make use of `->` on `ent`.

Comment: So `ent.d_name`?

Answer (score 3):

usually header files only contain data definitions and function prototypes.  Your function definition should almost certainly be in a C file.

If you look at the function `readdir` it returns a pointer to a `struct dirent` so your variable ent should be a pointer
struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp);

```
struct dirent *ent;
```

That will fix your error `invalid type argument of '->' (have struct dirent)`